# Deleting a file with the same name only if the new version can be saved

Tags: java

My current situation is:
I have test.txt and after an interval i want to save a newer version of test.txt using the same name, because in my application i am using the test.txt name to read the file.

I found that using the code below basically overrides the test.txt file if it already exists.

```
new FileWriter("test.txt", false);
```

My main concern using this code is that new FileWriter can throw errors (IOException and FileNotFound). I don't want it to delete the old test.txt if it's not possible to save the new version of test.txt.

Is there a way/option to guarantee that the old version of test.txt gets deleted only if the new version can get created/saved?
I don't want to get stuck in the situation where the old version gets deleted and the new version can't be saved.

Comment: I don't know that you can do it in one atomic line of code, but try this: 1) rename existing file, then 2) write new file. If 2 fails, then revert the renamed file back to the original file name.  If 2 succeeds then delete the renamed file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write your data to a new temp file and if that is finished delete test.txt and rename the temp file to test.txt.